# Why does this book suggest you can overload javascript constructors?

Tags: javascript

While I'm not a Javascript expert, I'm pretty familiar with it and have used it for years. As far as I know there is no ability to overload functions or constructors (from a language support perspective; of course you can basically simulate it).

So I want to get a MCSE and going through a study book for one of the exams I will take and I see what's included in the attached image. It appears as though the book is suggesting Javascript would choose the correct constructor (the one with no parameters, or the one with 3 parameters) based on whether you call it with 0 or 3 parameters. Is that right? I didn't think that Javascript did that. What am I missing here?

[image: Snippet from book]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You're not missing anything, your understanding is correct. There is no overloading in javascript and as pointed out the latter definition of `Book` just overrides the former.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. I thought it was pretty odd, and that the only reason it "works" is because it's really calling the function with 3 parameters without any arguments.

Comment: There are no words to express the disappointment of seeing this. Book is wrong. Terribly wrong. Author should fix that immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That defines `Book()` and then immediately redefines it, ignoring the previous definition. I'm not sure why you'd do that, and given how out of date this code is, ES6 introduces `class` which makes this all irrelevant, it may be a merely academic point now.

For example:

```
function F() { return 0; }
function F(a) { return 1; }
```

A reduction of their example into:

```
var a = [ F(), F('test') ];
```

Which they're claiming will be `[ 0, 1 ]` but is actually, and obviously `[ 1, 1 ]` since the *entire function was redefined*.

There's a lot of things about this code which are highly suspect.

The reason the code "works" at all is because JavaScript couldn't care less if you don't specify all the arguments, they're just left as `undefined`. That is a call to `F()` is the same as `F(undefined)`, or in their example, the second version runs and just sets `undefined` to those three properties.

I have a sneaking suspicion that whomever wrote that was still thinking in terms of a language like C++ with function overloading, something JavaScript does not have.

Comment: A lot of these exams are comically out of date. You're lucky it doesn't involve questions about C89 or Windows 3.1. Does the test site have a "Best viewed in Netscape Navigator" badge that advises having a screen of at least 800x600 pixels?

Comment: I was actually looking for more current exams but oddly there doesn't seem to be anything newer. Doesn't really matter though. I could almost pass the exam without studying but there are always really specific questions about features most people never use, or only need to spend 5 minutes googling to learn at the time they need it.

Comment: There are more current JavaScript-focused certifications, especially as it relates to React, Vue, or more common front-end frameworks.

Comment: for sure, but not that I can use to get an MCSE.